# Is it necessary to have data in the form of images to use Google Vision API for object identification?

Tags: computer-vision, google-vision

I'm planning to use Google Vision Api to identify and count objects from a video. I can get the data in terms of a good quality video format only. So, I want to know whether I can use it or will have to train the model with images only?

Comment: Check out the cloud vision API for videos: https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/

Comment: Thanks, will go through it.